# Is there a more efficient method for For-Next including If-Then statement?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

I am in a process of improving the efficiency of two macros. I have managed to improve all of their methods besides the one described on the title. It is fully functional, but I am sure there is a better way to right the part of the code I am providing below:

```
For Each cell2 In Range("L2:L" & lastrow2)
  If Not cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Then
    If cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "SOCHACZEW" Then
    cell2.Value = 31.2
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "SEKERPINAR" Then
    cell2.Value = 33
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "ATHENS" Then
    cell2.Value = 28
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "MECHELEN" Then
    cell2.Value = 33
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "TIMISOARA" Then
    cell2.Value = 34
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "STRANCICE" Then
    cell2.Value = 33
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "KLIPPAN" Then
    cell2.Value = 33
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "MATARO" Then
    cell2.Value = 33
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "KIEV" Then
    cell2.Value = 32
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "ROSTOV" Then
    cell2.Value = 32.6
    ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = "ITELLA" Then
    cell2.Value = 32
    End If
  End If
Next cell2
```

Comment: You can use `Select Case cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value` instead of your multiple `ElseIf`s

Comment: So, I should replace ElseIf with the  Select Case cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value ?

Comment: See my answer and code below, see if it helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine a few of your `ElseIf`s together, as they share the same result, together with switching to `Select Case`, your code could be shorter as follows:

```
For Each cell2 In Range("L2:L" & lastrow2)

    With cell2
        If Not .Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Then
            Select Case .Offset(0, -5).Value
                Case "SOCHACZEW"
                    .Value = 31.2

                Case "SEKERPINAR", "MECHELEN", "STRANCICE", "KLIPPAN", "MATARO"
                    .Value = 33

                Case "ATHENS"
                    .Value = 28

                Case "KIEV", "ITELLA"
                    .Value = 32

                Case "ROSTOV"
                    .Value = 32.6

                Case "TIMISOARA"
                    .Value = 34

            End Select
        End If
    End With

Next cell2
```

Comment: thanks a lot! so, in your opinion, your code is as efficient as possible right?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas with the current data you have provided yes.

Comment: And, one more question... If I didnt have Elseifs with same data, would it be worth using this method? what I am trying to say is whether this method is generally more efficient than the one I used

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas not sure, most likely you can google the benchmark performance between multiple `ElseIf` and `Select Case`, I just find the code "cleaner" and easier to debug (also if you want to add more scenarios in the future)

Answer (score 1):

@ShaiRado answer does make the code shorter, but for performance you should use an array to minimize the interaction with the range:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SetCities()
    Const COL_G = 1
    Const COL_K = 5
    Const COL_L = 6
    Dim r As Long, arr As Variant, lastrow2 As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'read entire range
    With ws
        lastrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range("G2:L" & lastrow2)
    End With
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not IsError(arr(r, COL_G)) And Not IsError(arr(r, COL_K)) Then
            If Len(arr(r, COL_K)) > 0 Then
                Select Case arr(r, COL_G)
                    Case "SOCHACZEW":   arr(r, COL_L) = 31.2

                    Case "SEKERPINAR", "MECHELEN", "STRANCICE", "KLIPPAN", "MATARO"
                                        arr(r, COL_L) = 33

                    Case "ATHENS":      arr(r, COL_L) = 28
                    Case "TIMISOARA":   arr(r, COL_L) = 34

                    Case "KIEV", "ITELLA"
                                        arr(r, COL_L) = 32

                    Case "ROSTOV":      arr(r, COL_L) = 32.6
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("G2:L" & lastrow2) = arr   'write entire range
End Sub
```

---

or at least turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating` before execution, and back on after

You should also fully qualify all ranges to be explicit about the Worksheet